# React: Accessing this.state inside function throws error

Tags: reactjs

I use the following component:

```
const NewProject = () =>  {
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

    const handleClickOpen = () => {
        setOpen(true);
    };

    const handleClose = () => {
        setOpen(false);
    };

    const addProject = () => {
        console.log(this.state.title)
    };

    function Form() {
        const [state, setState] = React.useState({
            title: "",
            description: "",
        })
        function handleChange(evt) {
            setState({
                ...state,
                [evt.target.id]: evt.target.value
            });
        }
        return (
            <form>
                <TextField
                    autoFocus
                    margin="dense"
                    id="title"
                    label="Project title"
                    type="text"
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    fullWidth
                    required
                />
                <TextField
                    autoFocus
                    margin="dense"
                    id="description"
                    label="Project description"
                    type="text"
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    fullWidth
                    multiline
                />
            </form>
        );
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="newProject">
                <Fab color="primary" aria-label="add" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
                    <AddIcon />
                </Fab>
            </div>
            <Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose} aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title">
                <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">New project</DialogTitle>
                <DialogContent>
                    <Form/>
                </DialogContent>
                <DialogActions>
                    <Button onClick={handleClose} color="secondary">
                        Cancel
                    </Button>
                    <Button onClick={addProject} color="primary">
                        Add
                    </Button>
                </DialogActions>
            </Dialog>
        </div>
    );
}
```

My problem is that `addProject` has no acces to `this.state`, so I get this error when clicking on the `Add` button: `typeerror: undefined has no properties`. How can I access the state inside of this function?

The answer is probably rather obvious for someone who spent more time with react. I'd be happy about a recommendation to properly understand how components and the state work with each other. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 const [state, setState] = React.useState({
            title: "",
            description: "",
        })
```

The above piece of code is inside Form component so NewProject can't access it, so declare it outside of NewProject but inside Form, also `this` is not required for accessing variable declared inside a functional component

```
const NewProject = () =>  {
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
    const [state, setState] = React.useState({
            title: "",
            description: "",
        })

    const handleClickOpen = () => {
        setOpen(true);
    };

    const handleClose = () => {
        setOpen(false);
    };

    const addProject = () => {
        console.log(state.title)
    };
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="newProject">
                <Fab color="primary" aria-label="add" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
                    <AddIcon />
                </Fab>
            </div>
            <Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose} aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title">
                <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">New project</DialogTitle>
                <DialogContent>
                    <Form {...{state, setState}}/>
                </DialogContent>
                <DialogActions>
                    <Button onClick={handleClose} color="secondary">
                        Cancel
                    </Button>
                    <Button onClick={addProject} color="primary">
                        Add
                    </Button>
                </DialogActions>
            </Dialog>
        </div>
    );
}

 function Form({state, setState}) {

        function handleChange(evt) {
            setState({
                ...state,
                [evt.target.id]: evt.target.value
            });
        }
        return (
            <form>
                <TextField
                    autoFocus
                    margin="dense"
                    id="title"
                    label="Project title"
                    type="text"
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    fullWidth
                    required
                />
                <TextField
                    autoFocus
                    margin="dense"
                    id="description"
                    label="Project description"
                    type="text"
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    fullWidth
                    multiline
                />
            </form>
        );
    }
```

Comment: this looks good, however, `handleChange` now doesn't set the value properly. I can only ever add one character.

Comment: @Hillcow, you should extract the form component outside of the NewProject component and pass setState as a prop to form component while using it inside NewProject

Comment: But I need the form inside of the component?

Comment: Awesome! Works now. Do you know about any resources with which I could understand what you actually did there?

Comment: I highly recommend this tutorial - https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html
 also https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206446/discussion-between-aldrin-p-vincent-and-hillcow).

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the below block outside of `Form` function for the state to be accessible to all the functions

```
 const [state, setState] = React.useState({
            title: "",
            description: "",
        })
```

Comment: Still get the same error plus `handleChange` doesn't work any more either.